# Within the CP, how can I filter the listed Entries based on a Lightswitch field value?

Tags: control-panel, search, lightswitch

I tried these kind of searches in the CP search field (on top of the Entry list):

- fieldHandle:true / fieldHandle:false
- fieldHandle:1 / fieldHandle:0
- fieldHandle:* / -fieldHandle:*
- fieldHandle:not 1 / fieldHandle:'not 1'
- etc.

Unfortunately, none of these returns the expected entries.

Comment: What version of Craft are you trying this on?

Comment: Craft Pro 3.4.30

Answer (score 0):

Lightswitch fields are a bit of an edge-case in searching because it can only be true/false (in the real boolean sense of true/false) so Craft doesn't explicitly index it in the searchindex table.

That's a bit awkward because even through there is a field setting "use this field's value for the search index" it's the one field where it doesn't apply.

Regardless, this should all be rectified for the upcoming Craft 4 release where we plan to make this possible.

Comment: Thank you Brad. In my case, I was primary looking for Lightswitch values that were TRUE and were returning nothing. In fact, the search index feature was disabled for this field, and you pointed it out. Now `fieldHandle:1` returns something. That's (almost) enough for me :)

Comment: Just one more thing: after enable the search index again for this field, `./craft resave/users` and `./craft resave/entries` had not the expected effect. The Lightswitch field values were still not indexed. I had to re-save manually these Entries to get the index up to date.